# Autocomplete causes text to scroll to right

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, autocomplete

Autocomplete on my editable `combobox` works fine for short items.

However, if the selected string is too wide and does not fit in the `combobox`, it scrolls horizontally to the right, presumably as a result of the autocomplete feature selecting the remainder of the string.

This hides the current location of the point at which the user is typing.

How do I get it to keep the position of the caret visible to the user?

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxCustomer"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource customerViewSource}}"
    TextSearch.TextPath="CustomerDisplay"
    SelectedValue="{Binding CustomerID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"
    SelectedValuePath="ID"  
    SelectionChanged="comboBoxCustomer_SelectionChanged"
    StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
    IsEditable="True" >
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerDisplay}" Foreground="{Binding ActiveColour}" />
      </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ScrollToHome` method on `textbox` of `combobox`.

```
   private void comboBoxCustomer_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)comboBoxCustomer.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", comboBoxCustomer);
        tb.ScrollToHome();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for adding answer.

Comment: This worked for me, but does the text "bounce" for you or did you figure out a way to stop the text from "bouncing" back and forth.

Comment: @adondero It does bounce briefly, but I had hardly even noticed it, and it does not interfere with the typing. I am fine with that. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: @EMett  Not at this time, I was asking before I spent time trying to figure it out.  I will try to get back to it and see if I can figure out anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxCustomer"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource customerViewSource}}"
    TextSearch.TextPath="CustomerDisplay"
    SelectedValue="{Binding CustomerID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"
    SelectedValuePath="ID"  
    SelectionChanged="comboBoxCustomer_SelectionChanged"
    StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
    IsEditable="True" >
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerDisplay}" Foreground="{Binding ActiveColour}" **TextAlignment="Left"** />
      </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I had already tried `TextAlignment` it does not make any difference.